# How to setup Apache for more simultaneous connections by user?

Tags: apache-2.2, connection, firefox

I run a virtual CentOS 5 server with Apache 2 and PHP under FastCGI, using mod_fcgid. I've built an application which relies heavily on Ajax, and in one case uses a popup with PHP flushing to allow the application to work in realtime during a long time.

The issue is that when I connect to one ajax-script I'm locked to that script until it is finished. The same goes for the popup. I don't seem to be able to serve more than one request at a time.

I read in another post that it's most likely the client (Firefox) that causes the issue, but Firefox "network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server" is set to 10.

How can I allow either the browser or the server (whichever is causing the issue) to accept more than one connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the number of connections is ip bound in most browsers, you can spread your content across multiple ips/domains to enhance performance. you can find a more detailed explanation at [yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#split). there are also some more performance tips for your frontend performance.

a good tool for messauring frontend performance in firefox is [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/). it does not only messaure performance, but also gives hints about how to improve your performance.